# How to auto generate Java 8 code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I generate Java 8 specific code in eclipse IDE.
For example using collections, on pressing `CNTL + ENTER`; instead of generating following

```
 Collection<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

it should generate

```
 Collection<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

NOTE: However `CNTL + 1` does convert the anonymous interface to lambda expression.

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Mars.2 version

Comment: I've just added my answer, I think I found why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the correct JRE System Library for your project and the autocompletion will change accordingly to the Java version used.

I have created a project named `test-java-1.6` and I have verified that the Java autocomplete does not support diamond operator because of old java version.

The autocomplete behaviour changed immediately after the Java version update.

Here how to specify the java execution environment:

[image: Properties for java project]

And how to change it to a newer version, here you should choose **JavaSE-1.8**

[image: Edit Library]

Comment: I'm using eclipse neon.3, may be the behaviour is a little different. Double check also `Java Code Stype` menu in `Project Properties` dialog.